# Visual Studio Code shortcut to come out of the current or enclosing block of code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any shortcut in visual studio code to come out of the current block of code. For example -

```java
while (!q.isEmpty()) {
    Oranges obj = q.pollFirst();
    ans = Math.max(obj.time, ans);
    for (int[] d : neighbors) {
        int r = obj.x + d[0];
        int c = obj.y + d[1];
        int t = obj.time + 1;//Cursor position
        if (r >= 0 && r < grid.length && c >= 0 && c < grid[0].length && grid[r][c] == 1) {
            q.offer(new Oranges(r, c, t));
            grid[r][c] = 2;
        }
    }//Target Position
}
```

In code above, suppose my cursor is at **Cursor position** and I want to come directly out of the current block of code or enclosing for-loop to **Target Position**.
If there is any extension that can do it then please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a keyboard shortcut called "Go to Bracket" (`editor.action.jumpToBracket`) that gets you close to what you want. Its default keys are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>.

From where you have `//Cursor position`, it will jump down to the inside of the brace where you have `//Target Position`. So:

```java
while (!q.isEmpty()) {
    Oranges obj = q.pollFirst();
    ans = Math.max(obj.time, ans);
    for (int[] d : neighbors) {
        int r = obj.x + d[0];
        int c = obj.y + d[1];
        int t = obj.time + 1;//Cursor position
        if (r >= 0 && r < grid.length && c >= 0 && c < grid[0].length && grid[r][c] == 1) {
            q.offer(new Oranges(r, c, t));
            grid[r][c] = 2;
        }
    <cursor will move here>}//Target Position
}
```

If you are quick with your arrow keys, you could navigate around your code quite fast with this once you get it down.

Comment: Hi @Timothy G. Could you please tell the name of this key binding or shortcut so that I can change this shortcut to custom keys.

Comment: @MayankKumarThakur edited my post to add that

Comment: Thanks @Timothy G. It works. If you know some more easy shortcuts for vscode then please do share.